# CSS Media Query based on element width

Tags: html, css, media-queries, element, resizable

Having a modal DIV containing responsive tabs that change from horizontal to vertical on min-width (720px) for example.

This div is Resizable by the user!

So the problem is if the user resizes the div to 600px no responsive change occurs, that's because the screen width didn't change.

My question is: is there any hack or way to make a USER RESIZABLE DIV respond to its width change instead of the screen width?
I tried to figure out how to do it with calc, but I think it would be something like :

```
calc(100% - div-width)= ... etc.
```

but I don't think it's supported this way by CSS.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Right now? NO, "element queries" do not yet exist although I understand they are being worked on as part of a next CSS spec.

Comment: What width do you want when the `<div>` is smaller than 720px? What width do you want when the `<div>` is wider than 720px?

Comment: You can combine css-rules easily. Eg `width: 720px; max-width: 100%;`. This way your div is 720px wide, but will never get wider than its parent.

Comment: @Pieterjan for example when the div is resized smaller than 720px the TABS MENU inside it change to vertical tabs and when it's over 720px it change to horizontal tabs menu

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve the result you're looking for as you said in the comments above, i think one great way is to use css `grid` or `flex`. You can make your div responsive with one of them without the need of a media query.
Example: `display: flex;` `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Comment: Your solution is understable but in my case the DIV contains a TAB NAVIGATION PANELS (like sections) and they are horizontal and i my code they change to Vertical tabs with the content beside, so on media screen it is ok but since the containing div is a Modal resizable div, so it impossible to do it while changing the div dimension only

Comment: I understand. Then can you provide a snippet of your code so i can take a further look??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex; and flex-wrap:wrap` as xhoni says. Also i offer you to use font-size with media-queries because if the screen width decrease but your font is not. It may occured some display or design problem.